# Stuck at query. I want total number of students in each board

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables student and grade.
They are linked by PK FK relation from Student (count) to Grades (marksID).
I have to select percentage of student who has scored more than 70 percent marks, Board wise.
Every city has its own board.
The query is:

```
select g3.board,(count(g2.percentag)/ count(board))*100
from  loadbise.grade as g2, loadbise.student as g3
where g2.marksID=g3.countt
and percentag > 70
group by g3.board;
```

I know the value for count(ge.percentag) and count(board) is same.
I am stuck at this count(board) point.
I want total Number of students in each board in count(board).
What am I missing???
The Schema is..
[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing `count(distinct studentId)`, or whatever the equivalent field is in your table.

Comment: Tried. Same old result

Comment: Could you add to your question database schema?

Comment: its very large database. :(
countt is primary key.. They problem is nature of query.

Comment: I attached the schema @fabulaspb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this SQL query. For each board I've calculated count of students with percentage > 70 and total count of students.

```
SELECT T.board,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT G.countt) FROM loadbise.Grades AS G
            JOIN loadbise.Student AS S ON S.countt = G.countt
        WHERE G.percentage > 70
                  AND S.board = T.board)
        /
       (SELECT COUNT(S.countt) FROM loadbise.Student AS S
        WHERE S.board = T.board) * 100
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT board
    FROM Student AS S) AS T
```